# Failed to get StepCount Using Google Fit API

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, google-fit

Login to Google Fit account success but step count is not showing. Please help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE=101;
    public static  final String TAG="StepCounter";
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;

    private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
    private boolean authInProgress = false;

    private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static  Boolean loggedIn=false;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect to the Fitness API
        Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");
        mClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mClient.isConnected()) {
            mClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mClient.isConnecting() && !mClient.isConnected()) {
                    mClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);



        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
        }

        buildFitnessClient();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {       //worker thread adding data to the array list(the data can be from database)



            @Override
            public void run() {



                while(loggedIn) {

                     readData();


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
        }).start();







    }

    private void buildFitnessClient() {

        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                loggedIn=true;
                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                // Put application specific code here.











                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                                if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                    // Show the localized error dialog
                                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                            MainActivity.this, 0).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                                // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                                // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                                // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                                if (!authInProgress) {
                                    try {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                        authInProgress = true;
                                        result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                                REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG,
                                                "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .build();







    }
```

> The function for reading the stepcount from googlefit account

```
  private void readData() {

        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<DataSet>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DataSet dataSet) {
                                long total =
                                        dataSet.isEmpty()
                                                ? 0
                                                : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Total steps: " + total);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(total),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
    }




}
```

> When successfully login then readData() is called but no Log msg or Toast message is getting.

On debugging the `readData()` code is executing but no result is showing.

Comment: What error you are get in onFailure Method?

Comment: E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a OAuth2.0 scope. Make sure you have selected all of these.

[image]